# Changed PHP version to 8.1 but WordPress thinks we're using version 7.4 instead?

Tags: php, wordpress

Anyone might have experience this issue before?

On my cPanel the "Select PHP Version" dropdown is showing that 8.1 is selected but when I go to my WordPress dashboard it says "PHP Update Required".

[image: Screenshot of WordPress notice asking the user to update PHP]

To verify which PHP version exactly is the one that my site is using I added the below code as `phpinfo.php` and access then checked `example.com/phpinfo.php` and it shows that I'm on 7.4.

```
<?php

phpinfo( );

?>
```

Let me know if you have suggestions on how I could fix this. Thank you all in advance.

I tried changing the PHP version to 8 back to 8.81 but nothing special happened.

Comment: You may need to contact your. host and find out why cPanel is not changing the version of PHP for you.

Comment: Unfortunately my webhost is not really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is for your main site, I recommend that you check your `cPanel > File Manager > public_html folder > look for .htaccess file` chances are, you have a PHP version specified in your `htaccess` file that overrides the PHP version set on your cPanel.

You may want to look out for `“ea-php74”` in your .htaccess and update it to 8.1 to work.

You can also try replacing it by adding this PHP handler at the top of the file `.htaccess` file:

```
php – BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
php – END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Source: [WordPress Org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-version-on-host-differs-from-wp/)

Comment: It worked!! I found that I have a php 7.4 and updated that to 8.1 and now the error in WordPress not showing anymore!! Thanks a lot for your help!!!